# Initialize the Ads SDK or not

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, admob

Do I need to initialize the ads SDK in the main activity or not at all

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
```

- If I follow the firebase **website** instructions it says you
  should initialize.
- And if I follow the firebase **assistant** in the tools in android
  studio it doesn't mention it at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize this as soon as possible and per launch Like this.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    // ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), myAppId);
    } 
}
```

This is the correct way to do this and it worked for me hope it will for you too.

Comment: I've found that I should initialize it, but google studio guide made me question this, I though maybe they removed the need to do it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to initialize. It automatically gets initialized when you request your first ad. Running this early just saves you very small time when you want to show an ad. [Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/kayQ3VZJqkU)

But if you intend to initialize, you should do it in your Application since it needs to be called only once.